# React "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I looked at many other answers but I couldn't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
// userInputActions.js

...

export function dummy() {
    console.log('dummy function called');
}

...

// *userInputPage.js*

import * as userInputActions from '../actions/userInputActions';

class UserInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
    };

    // When un-commented it shows '*f dummy()*' is imported 
    // console.log('actions: ', userInputActions);

    this.dummy = this.dummy.bind(this);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid align-items-center">
        <FieldLevelValidationForm onSubmit={this.dummy}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      ...userInputActions
    }, dispatch
  );

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserInput);
```

Note 'FieldLevelValidationForm' is a `redux-form` and `onSubmit` is one of the form function arguments.

I tried various things and the bind function does not work. Can someone please let me know where am I going wrong. I think it has something to do with the render() function and the lifetime of the component but I do not know enough yet.

**Edit**
Thank you - learned a lot from all answers. All of them work. I wish I could give more than one check-mark. However, I think the most appropriate use for my case is to call it as a prop and dispatch an action as so on.

Comment: this.dummy hasn't been initialised with a value when you try and bind it. Did you mean to do `this.dummy = userInputActions.dummy; this.dummy = this.dummy.bind(this)?`

Comment: Or just `this.dummy = userInputActions.dummy.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dummy` function is passed as props, so you should access it with `this.props.dummy` in your `render()` instead.

There's also no need to bind it to `this` as it's not using the `this` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The dummy function you are trying to bind is not in `this` class. So it would just be:

```
this.dummy = userInputActions.dummy.bind(this);
```

Comment: As @riwu says though, it's unnecessary in your current use case.

Answer (score 0):

Function definition of `dummy` is missing.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { };
  this.dummy = this.dummy.bind(this);
}

dummy(e) {
  // form submission action
  userInputActions.dummy(); // maybe
}

render () {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid align-items-center">
      <FieldLevelValidationForm onSubmit={this.dummy}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```